# How can I generate this log scale plot?

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions

I have some results on a study and I want to plot them like people do in the literature. However I couldn't get how to plot as the plot in the image.

[image: Reference Plot]

Seems like it is a log-log scale but vertical axis has increments of 0.1 instead of multiples.

Comment: What software are you using to plot it? Mathematica, R, etc?

Comment: I tried with Excel but I can switch to another software if Excel is not capable of plotting this.

Comment: 5 seconds of google gave me this: http://smallbusiness.chron.com/make-log-scale-excel-29180.html

Comment: I know how to plot a log-log scale in Excel. However I'm asking something different. Did you check the reference plot?